# Atom python-import-magic

Tags: python-import, atom-editor

I keep getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQjX1.jpg) when I am trying to use python-import-magic in spite of all the necessary packages in place. It seems the error is getting triggered because I have two different Python versions - one that came with Anaconda that I need to use and the other possibly from my Windows 10 installation. Is there anyway of making apm aware of which Python version the extension is meant for?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQjX1.jpg)

Comment: are you sure you installed the package for the same interpreter used by atom? or maybe you use an environment and the packages need to be installed in anaconda itself?

Comment: I do have two versions of Python - one within the Anaconda env and the other that possibly came with Windows 10. I am unable to uninstall the later for some reason. Any work around that you can think of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: that path in the image lead to the system anaconda? or the anaconda within the env? or the other python? are you sure that atom use the interpreter in the anaconda env and don't use the system anaconda?

Comment: please update the question rather than answering in comments